# Recent question feed is titled "top questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, title

This is a small bug that I just noticed. Low priority.

The feed link at the bottom of the sites is a link to the most recent questions, but when you subscribe to that RSS feed, it is being given the title of "Top Questions" instead of "Recent Questions".

Answer (score 1):

I updated the titles to a lot of the feeds to be more descriptive.

EDIT: I was referring to the HTML links (+ `<meta>` headers) to the RSS on the page, which many clients echo back. I also just changed the actual feed title per your request.

Comment: I just added the feed from the main home page and it still is titled "Top Questions" in my reader.  What does Top Questions mean?  There's no Tab called Top Questions so I don't know what it even means.  Is that the title you want that feed to have?